# Area of $x^3 -2x^2 + x - 2$ and $x$-axis

Tags: integration

I know it supposed to be so easy. But how to set up the boundaries? [image: full question here]

Comment: A hint could be that x-axis is limited by where expression (y-coordinate) equals = 0.

Comment: Another hint:  it’s $(x-2)(x^2+1)$

Comment: Are you supposed to find the area between the graph of $x^3-2x^2+x-2$, the $x$-axis, and the $y$-axis?

Comment: Question says only x axis

Comment: The questions asks for area between x-axis and $f(x)$ , not $F(x)$. What you have provided was $F(x)$.

Comment: What is $f(x)$ ?

Comment: I wrote a solution, please check it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(x) \mathrm dx \Rightarrow f(x) = F'(x)\ \ \ \text{by FTOC}$$

Find $f(x)$ and then try finding the area.

Comment: What is FTOC? @Rick

Comment: Oh that's Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTOC)

Answer (score 1):

Since $F(a)=0$ we get $$ a^3-2a^2+a-2=0$$ which implies $a=2$

The rigeon that $F(x)>0$ is for $x>2$

The area bounded by the points $2$ and $x$ is $$A(x) =  \int_2^x f(t) \mathrm dt =x^3-2x^2+x-2$$

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a cubic polynomial with real coefficients, and so it will either have one or three real roots(because complex roots occur in conjugate pairs). Now, when you put x=2, the function is 0. So, the question is incomplete!

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have edited the question,

it looks like it is asking for the area between $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis,

not the area between $F(x)=x^3-2x^2+x-2$ and the $x$-axis.

The derivative of $F(x)=x^3-2x^2+x-a$ is $f(x)=3x^2-4x+1$,

so we have $\int_a^x 3t^2-4t+1=t^3-2t^2+t|_a^x=x^3-2x^2+x-(a^3-2a^2+a);$

and $a=a^3-2a^2+a$ and $a\ne0$ means $a=2$.

The area surrounded by the $x$-axis and $f(x)=3x^2-4x+1=(3x-1)(x-1)$ is $$\left|\int_{1/3}^1 f(t)dt\right|=\left|F(x)|_{1/3}^1\right|.$$

Comment: Yes. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt = x^3-2x^2+x-a$$

Taking the derivative:

$$F'(x) = f(x) = 3x^2-4x+1$$

So, reintegrating, you have:

$$F(x) = \int_a^x (3t^2-4t+1)dt = \left. t^3-2t^2+t \right]_a^x = x^3-2x^2+x-(a^3-2a^2+a) = x^3-2x^2+x-a^3+2a^2-a$$

This implies that $a^3-2a^2=0 \Longrightarrow a^2(a-2)=0 \Longrightarrow a=0,a=2$, but you are given $a\neq 0$.

$$F(x) = x^3-2x^2+x-2 = (x-2)(x^2+1)$$

This is a product of two real numbers, so it is positive only when both factors share the same sign. Since $x^2+1$ is always positive for all real $x$, you only care when the first factor is positive. $x-2$ is positive when $x>2$. Thus, $F(x)>0$ for $x>2$.

Finally, you are looking for the area between the $x$-axis and $3x^2-4x+1 = (3x-1)(x-1)$. Since the $x$-axis is above your function, you are looking for:

$$\int_{\tfrac{1}{3}}^1 (0-(3x^2-4x+1))dx = F\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)-F(1) = \dfrac{4}{27}$$

Comment: Yes. Thank you..